# Is it possible to map multiple columns with the same data type to a new data type in sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

For example, if I want to import a table from RDBMS to hive and my table has 10 columns of type datetime and I want to convert all of those columns to timestamp in hadoop, how can I convert all the columns at once.

This will convert one column to the timestamp datatype:

```
sqoop import \

--table table_name \

--connect:sqlserver://servername \

--username user --password pw \

--map-column-hive column_with_date=timestamp\

--as-parquetfile \

--hive-import \

--hive-table table_name
```

How would I do this without writing 10 mapping commands

Comment: you need to write it for all columns. There is no short cut for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no short cut , you have to write for all columns, please check the documentation.[Sqoop user guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html)